# Is libido in men greater than women? Or is it the other way round?

Tags: mahabharata, women, sex, kama, men

There is a [popular notion](https://www.huffingtonpost.com/nikki-gloudeman/the-truth-about-men-women-and-libido_b_5614694.html) that men crave for sex more than women. And medical science seems to [agree with it](https://www.webmd.com/sex/features/sex-drive-how-do-men-women-compare#1).

But what do Hindu scriptures say about this?

For example, the Mahābhārata version available at sacred-texts.com [says](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b127.htm) the following although I'm not sure if it's talking about female libido or the duties of a husband in general.

> As the sacred fire waits for libations to be poured upon it when the hour for Homa arrives, even so a woman, when her functional period is over, expects an act of congress with her husband. One that never approaches one's spouses at any other time save after the functional period, is said to observe the vow of Brahmacharya.

Do scriptures besides Mahābhārata discuss this?

Comment: Adding "scripture" to every question not good...

Comment: Yes, Manu Smriti does. The popular notion exists because of 2 reasons - men have an option of control (whether to choose naishtika brahmacharya or gruhasthashrama at the end of studies). Talking about control for women does not arise, because they are expected to marry and those with explicit signs of libido are deemed something else by society. Two - men's biological cycle, and physical energy are much longer, so it seems like they have more libido. In practicality, female libido is higher but for shorter duration.. forget which text, but they mention a comparative number between the two.

Comment: But to your point, fulfilling it is also mentioned as husband's duty. So two-fold.

Comment: Libido of a man is indeed greater than a woman, due to natural & biological reasons. That's why a man is allowed to have multiple wives or mate multiple women. The natural tendency of a man is polygamous. However, scriptures may not say anything on this directly.

Comment: I don't find this question off-topic.

Comment: Something close to this is discussed in Mahabharata Anusasana Parva, Section XII.

Comment: This question is not off-topic. OP wants to know from Hindu Scriptures.

Comment: "Do scriptures besides Mahābhārata discuss this?"  The passage from MB is irrelevant here.. it's not talking about libido of women being higher or lower than in men.. so, it's not discussing **this**.. u can remove this passage and ask ur question.. if this isn't off-topic that won't be either.

Comment: As per *Chanakya Neeti*, it is other way round: स्त्रीणा द्विगुण अहारो ळज्जा चापि चतुर्गुणा।
साहसं षडगुणं चैव **कामश्चाष्टगुणः** स्मृतः॥ (In comparison to a man) A woman is having two times more appetite, four times more shyness, six times more courage and **eight times more the sexual desire**.

Comment: As @Rickross rightly said in comment, there is no purpose of the Mahabharata passage kept in the Qn. The passage is about Brahmacharya, while your Qn is about libido. How are they related? It misleads the users to an off topic discussion.

Comment: As I stated in my answer, the MBH passage in the question seems like the summary of the passage from GP @iammilind. It's just that MB doesn't offer any reasoning.

Comment: *sigh*.  The verse is talking about the grhasta's duty to fulfill pitR RNa by begetting progeny. Not what you think it does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Hindu scriptures, the sex drive is stronger in women.

The line from Mahābhārata in the question is closely related to the guidance below from Garuḍa Purāṇa ([astrojyoti.com](http://www.astrojyoti.com/garudapurana-6.htm)):

> **COPULATION PROHIBITED ON CERTAIN DAYS**
>
> An ideal wife is one who obeys the commands of her husband without any inhibition. According to the scriptures the best time for a married couple to copulate is after the woman has had her menstruation, especially till sixteen days after her periods have commenced are considered best for this purpose. But, there are also certain days on which making sexual contacts is prohibited - the first four days after her periods have started, Ashtami, Chaturdashi, Amavasya and Purnima are few such days. If the above given rules are followed then a couple can beget worthy sons possessing good qualities. **Considering the fact that a woman has sexual urge eight times more than a man, scriptures have also advised a man not to overlook the sexual urge of his wife** and to satisfy her without bothering about the prohibited days.

[*Chanakya Neeti*, translated by B.K. Chaturvedi](https://www.amazon.in/Chanakya-Neeti-B-K-Chaturvedi/dp/8128400487/) (thanks to [@YDS](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/24781/is-libido-in-men-greater-than-women-or-is-it-the-other-way-round#comment73749_24781) for the reference) says:

> **Woman**
>
> स्त्रीणा द्विगुण अहारो लज्जा चापि चतुर्गुणा । 
>  
>   साहसं षड्गुणं चैव कामश्चाष्टगुणः स्मृतः ।। 57 ।।
>
> Streenaa Dvigun Ahaaro Lajjaa Chaapi Chaturgunaa. 
>   Saahasam Shadgunam Chaiv Kaamashchachaashatgunah Smritah.
>
> (In comparison to a man) A woman is having two times more appetite, four times more shyness, six times more courage and **eight times more the sexual desire**.

[J. L. Shastri's translation](https://archive.org/stream/GarudaPuranaEnglishMotilal3VolumesIn1/Garuda%20Purana%20English%20-%20Motilal%20-%203%20Volumes%20in%201#page/n337/mode/1up) of Garuḍa Purāṇa says the same thing:

> **I.109   Bṛhaspati-nīti-sāra**
>
> ...
>
> 33. The diet of a woman is twice as much as that of a 
>   man; shrewdness four times, energy is six times and **amorousness is eight times as much as that of a man**.

Comment: Haha. Really. **8 Times!** quite strange than reality. And **twice the food**. Even a starving women eats not more than a leaf

Comment: Yes, the ideas presented in scripture as 'reality' are sometimes different from the _actual_ reality.

Answer (score 2):

Hindu scriptures **may not be discussing "libido" at all**.

There is a famous so called verse from ChAnakya Niti:

> स्त्रीणा द्विगुण **अहारो** लज्जा चापि चतुर्गुणा ।
>   साहसं षड्गुणं चैव **काम**श्चाष्टगुणः स्मृतः

I had came across these quotes of "X times this, Y times that" several years back. Later I found out them to be misconceptions.

- अहार, which is wrongly interpreted as आहार & hence translated as "appetite", seems out of place. I have never seen a wife eating twice her husband; not even more. Similarly "bravery" is a personal attribute, which differs from person to person.
- काम means "desire". For "libido", there may not be proper word at all.
- गुण is least likely to be translated as multiplier. How can there be equations of such accuracy about human aspects!